How can I write and format descriptions/messages over multiple lines with Discord Bots in Python?
I am currently trying to code an embed for a discord bot in python and I am wondering how I can spread the text over or format the message so that it goes over multiple lines. Essentially being able to create a newline whenever I want. I'm not sure how to do this right now and my description for example in the code below doesn't have any paragraphing however I would like to change this.
Shown below is the current code and output I have and as well as what I am trying to mirror. Thank you all in advance! (And yes I'm a beginner)

Current Program (using discord.py - the discord library)
Current Output
Desired Output


Please copy your code here instead of using a screenshot.

You add \n where you want newlines. Also, post your code as text, not images.

You can create a new variable named message and then put your string formating inside it using \n. Then use the message variable inside as an argument in your function.
For example,
 <your code here>....description = message, color=0x00ff00)

generally you would just add a \n in the text. you can do this in any string and it works in messages and embeds. It's pretty universal
for example
mystring = "this is a multiline string \n this is a new line \n this is too!"

would output like so
this is a multiline string
this is a new line
this is too!

in your case your string would look like this
description = "# Overview\n > help <command> shows information \n etc \n etc \n etc"

